Play small duration sound with MediaPlayer or SoundPool on button click
I have an android application written in Kotlin & jetpack compose. The application is running on a device with physical keyboard.
My goal is to play a sound every time I click a button.
Ideally, I want to play a sound of small duration so when I am making fast typing I want to play one sound for each button click. Sounds of large duration, work but sometimes they are not as frequent as the frequency of typing.
Initially, I tried to use MediaPlayer. The problem with this approach is that when I use specific sounds, the application crashes and I get null pointer exception. The application does not even start. This happens mostly with small sounds.
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private lateinit var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer

    @OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.keypress33)

        setContent {
            DemoTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    
                    val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
                    val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current
                    val cursorPosition = remember { mutableStateOf(1) }
                    var textFieldValue by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue(text = "1", selection = TextRange(cursorPosition.value)) ) }


                    Box(
                        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                    ) {


                        OutlinedTextField(
                            value = textFieldValue,
                            onValueChange = { newValue ->
                                textFieldValue = newValue
                            },
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .focusRequester(focusRequester)
                        )

                        LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
                            focusRequester.requestFocus()
                            keyboardController?.hide()
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }



    override fun onDestroy() {
        mediaPlayer.release()
        super.onDestroy()
    }



    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    override fun dispatchKeyEvent(event: KeyEvent): Boolean {
        if (event?.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            playSound()
        }
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event)
    }

    private fun playSound() {
        if (::mediaPlayer.isInitialized) {
            mediaPlayer.start()
        }
    }

}


On the other hand, I have tried the SoundPool. There are other kind of issues here. The application does not crash, but it does not play any sound. If I change the sound and use something with little longer duration, it works but after a few clicks, it stops working.

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private lateinit var soundPool: SoundPool
    private var soundId: Int = 0
    private var isSoundLoaded = false

    @OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)


        setContent {
            DemoTheme {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {

                    val attributes = AudioAttributes.Builder()
                        .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ASSISTANCE_SONIFICATION)
                        .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                        .build()

                    soundPool = SoundPool.Builder()
                        .setAudioAttributes(attributes)
                        .setMaxStreams(2)
                        .build()

                    soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener { _, _, status ->
                        if (status == 0) {
                            isSoundLoaded = true
                        }
                    }

                    soundId = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.keypress, 1)


                    val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
                    val keyboardController = LocalSoftwareKeyboardController.current
                    val cursorPosition = remember { mutableStateOf(1) }
                    var textFieldValue by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue(text = "1", selection = TextRange(cursorPosition.value)) ) }


                    Box(
                        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
                    ) {


                        OutlinedTextField(
                            value = textFieldValue,
                            onValueChange = { newValue ->
                                textFieldValue = newValue
                            },
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .focusRequester(focusRequester)
                        )

                        LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
                            focusRequester.requestFocus()
                            keyboardController?.hide()
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }



    override fun onDestroy() {
        soundPool.release()
        super.onDestroy()
    }



    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    override fun dispatchKeyEvent(event: KeyEvent): Boolean {
        if (event?.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            playSound()
        }
        return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event)
    }

    private fun playSound() {
        if (isSoundLoaded) {
            soundPool.play(
                soundId,
                1.0f,
                1.0f,
                1,
                0,
                1.0f
            )
        }

    }

}



can you share you exception, for me your exoPlayer code working fine

I would recommend you to crop the sound you at 1/3 or 1/2 and retry. I wish I could attach somehow the sounds that I am using.

I know it sounds stupid, but changing the file from mp3 to wav fixed the issue.
After committing to my branch, pushing, merging with develop branch, I switched to develop and I made a pull from origin and I noticed the following difference.
For some reason the mp3 file was 0 bytes. Probably that caused the NullPointerException.

The only thing I did was to import the mp3 file to Audacity and export it as wav file.
